# I'm having a problem with my output producing an empty canvas. Is there a problem with my points being appended to the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this 2d point class that Im trying to plot the points graphically using tkinter canvas. The points need to be individual instances of the 2d point class, each with random x- and y- components that are within the width and height of the canvas(set to 800x800).The plotted points shoulf have a radius of 0 and random colors. The point radius and point colors are class variables of the Coordinate System class.

```
import math
from fractions import Fraction
from random import randint
from Tkinter import *
# the 2D point class
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # Mutators and Accessors
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

    # String function
    def __str__(self):
        floatX = float(str(self.x))
        floatY = float(str(self.y))
        return "({},{})".format(floatX, floatY)

    # Distance function
    def dist(self, other):
        distance = math.sqrt(((self.x - other.x)**2)+((self.y - other.y)**2))
        return "{}".format(distance)

    # Midpoint function
    def midpt(self, other):
        x_midpoint = float(str(((self.x + other.x))))/2
        y_midpoint = float(str(((self.y + other.y)/2)))
        return Point(x_midpoint, y_midpoint)

# the coordinate system class: (0,0) is in the top-left corner
# inherits from the Canvas class of Tkinter
class CoordinateSystem(Canvas):
    point_colors = ["black", "red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "yellow", "magenta"]
    radius = 0

    def __init__(self, master):
        Canvas.__init__(self, master, bg = "white")
        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        self.point = []

    def plotPoints(self, n):
        for i in range(NUM_POINTS):
            x = randint(0, WIDTH-1)
            y = randint(0, HEIGHT-1)
            self.point.append(Point(x, y))

    def plot(self, x, y):
        color = self.point_colors[randint(0, len(self.point_colors)-1)]
        self.create_rectangle(x, y, x+self.radius*2, y+self.radius*2, outline = color, fill = color)

##########################################################
# ***DO NOT MODIFY OR REMOVE ANYTHING BELOW THIS POINT!***
# the default size of the canvas is 800x800
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
# the number of points to plot
NUM_POINTS = 5000

# create the window
window = Tk()
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(WIDTH, HEIGHT))
window.title("2D Points...Plotted")
# create the coordinate system as a Tkinter canvas inside the window
s = CoordinateSystem(window)
# plot some random points
s.plotPoints(NUM_POINTS)
# wait for the window to close
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas is blank because the `CoordinateSystem.plot()` method is never called. Here's one way to fix that:

```
    def plotPoints(self, n):
        for i in range(NUM_POINTS):
            x = randint(0, WIDTH-1)
            y = randint(0, HEIGHT-1)
            self.point.append(Point(x, y))

        for point in self.point:            # ADDED
            self.plot(point.x, point.y)     # ADDED
```

Also note that you don't really need to pass `plotPoints()` the `n` argument, since it's not using it.